# Pop up password protect

Tags: javascript

**Please not that I fully understand this is a dumb ass idea, but its not my idea.**

We need to deter people visiting  a certain page on our site. It's written in ASP and I don'tknow ASP! Can anyone tell me how I can have a pop up box load when the URL is visited where by people have to enter a username / password.

The user name / password should be stored in the javascript.

(Yes I know)

The only real requirement is that this happen anytime the page is loaded and it stays on that page.

So the page is test.asp - javascript pops up they enter credentials and if right remain on test.asp

Thanks

Comment: do you have any JS frameworks on the page already? If so, you can make this easy (very, very wrong, but easy and pretty)

Comment: Please tell me when you say "the user name / password should be stored in the javascript" you mean "the password they type" and not the password they need to authenticate against.

Comment: I hope that you know that people can just view source and see the credentials or just turn off javascript on their browsers and then they won't have to enter anything. You should show this to the person that has this idea.

Comment: What's wrong with a proper `.htaccess` HTTP Basic Auth protection? You know, one that actually works. :) You don't need to know ASP for that.

Comment: It is not totally dumb. You can store a hashed version of the password and look for some library that can calculate hashes. But turning Javascript of will give access to the site anyway ;)

Comment: What happens if they have javascript turned off?

Comment: It's on IIS so no HTAccess. I don't really mind if they have JS turned off as overall the idea is a bad idea. For anyone pointing out how easy this is to get around, I know. I really know, seriously I know... I cannot get across how much I actually know this and how I know its a bad, insecure idea. But its the idea... thats the idea and we have to use it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say ASP I assume you mean pre .NET. If so then I think a small change to the VB/HTML in the page would be better. Of course this is only an example and not a very secure one at that - but still it is a little better than a plain JS solution.

Example - thenameofthepage.asp

```
<%

needAuthentication = True

If Request.Form.Count > 0 Then 
    If Request.Form("username") <> "jon" Or Request.Form("password") <> "secret" Then
        ' Redirect to another URI
        Response.Redirect("/")
        Response.End
    End If
    needAuthentication = False
End If

%>
<html>
<body>
<%

If needAuthentication Then

%>
<form method="post" action="thenameofthepage.asp">
  <div>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></div>
  <div>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
<%

Else

%>
<p>Page content here</p>
<%

End If

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very very wrong indeed, but this should do:

```
var passwords = new Object;
passwords['some user'] = 'some password';

function check_password(tries){
    var username = prompt('Please enter your username');
    var password = prompt('Please enter your password');
    if(passwords[username] != password){
        if(tries == 3){
            window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
        }else{
            check_password(tries + 1);
        }
    }
}
check_password(1);
```

To make sure someone can't get the password right away you could use some hashing algorithm. And if you put `display:none` on all important elements you could make it only show the contents when "logged in"

Comment: Arrays only take numerical indexes, I think you want an object there.

Comment: @deceze: actually, both work ;)

See this link for an example: http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html

Comment: Well yes, because an Array is an Object as well (because everything is an Object in JS), so what you're doing is attaching custom properties to the Array object. So you're not actually using the Array as array. If you want a dictionary (hash/map), you're supposed to use Objects.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to create a modal dialog box using Javascript. There are reasonable tutorials  on doing so [here](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-modal-dialog.aspx) and [link text](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/javascript_modal_dialog.asp) and a list of pre-existing libraries that cover modal dialogs [here](http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html).

Using something like this for *authentication* is a violation of all that is holy. Please point out to whoever is requiring this how trivial it is to subvert this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is a dumb idea.

But have you thought about adding an extra thin layer of security.. i.e. instead of popping up the JavaScript modal (or in addition to), can you redirect to the password + '.asp'?

Example, the next page is called `something.asp`. So you can make the password `something` and then do a

```
window.location = userInput + '.asp';
```

It is *slightly* more obfuscated.