# ASP password protect improvement

Tags: asp-classic

I stumbled across a simplistic, but helpful way to password protect a page here:
[Pop up password protect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596690/pop-up-password-protect)

Here's the code:

```
<%

needAuthentication = True

If Request.Form.Count > 0 Then 
    If Request.Form("username") <> "jon" Or Request.Form("password") <> "secret" Then
        ' Redirect to another URI
        Response.Redirect("/")
        Response.End
    End If
    needAuthentication = False
End If

%>
<html>
<body>
<%

If needAuthentication Then

%>
<form method="post" action="thenameofthepage.asp">
  <div>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></div>
  <div>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
<%

Else

%>
<p>Page content here</p>
<%

End If

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Two questions:
1) How can I improve this that when the password fails it calls an alert box "Login Failed" and resets the form? 
2) How insecure is this?  Are there ASP methods to improve security?

A few notes:
No database involved -- this is just a page protected by one global password.
And, if you couldn't already tell, my ASP skills are non-existent.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: (alert working with failed login but page content loading anyway)

```
<%
needAuthentication = True
authenticationFailed = False

If Request.Form.Count > 0 Then 
    If Request.Form("password") <> "secret" Then
        authenticationFailed = True
    End If
    needAuthentication = False
End If

%>


<html>
<body>

<%
If needAuthentication Then

%>

<form method="post" action="passwordtest.asp">
  <div>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>

<%
Else

%>

<p>Page content here</p>

<%
End If

%>

<%
If authenticationFailed Then

%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Invalid login");
</script>

<%
End If
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean if the password fails?  You mean if the user's login id is "jon" but the password isn't "secret"?

Comment: Correct.  Wrong password entered.  I didn't even think about user -- I am actually prob going to use this without a "username".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like:

`authenticationFailed = False`

And then in the `Else` section of your statement, set `authenticationFailed = True`.

Then on your page have something like:

```
<%

If authenticationFailed Then

%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Invalid login");
</script>
<%
```

Security has many elements. Assuming you can keep the password secret, and assuming no one else can get their hands on this file, then so long as you access the site using HTTPS you should be fine :) - note that was a lot of "ifs" there.

If you want to know more about security, I would recommend googling the subject. Security is directly related to the technology you're using - although different technologies do try and make things easier in their own ways.

Oh and one additional thing - this method of logging in requires that you login every time you want to access a protected page. It doesn't remember it as you might expect. You'd need to investigate sessions for that - which is a topic all in itself: http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_sessions.asp.

Comment: Thanks for this, but something is not right -- I'm getting a 500 - internal server error when I try and load the page.

Comment: Its probably missing the End If - I was only firing the idea at you - you need to ensure the syntax etc it correct. Its been years since I used Classic ASP and I've never been a VB user.

Comment: I added the authenticationFailed = False right beneath the needAuthentication = True, and entered the 
'<%

If authenticationFailed Then

%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Invalid login");
</script>'
under the form markup

Comment: You probably just need to make sure all you if/else/end's match up. And you'll want to ensure the logic only sets it when the password is incorrect.

Comment: Progress!  And semi-success. Got the page to load when I straightened out the logic, and an incorrect password triggers the alert, BUT when the alert is cleared it loads the page anyway.  I'm guessing I need to set the needAuthentication = True, but where/how? Any thoughts?

Comment: You should only set needAuthentication = True if login succeeds - so move it inside that if statement.

Hmmm, do you even need the redirect? Aren't you just loading the same page again?

Comment: Yeah, I removed the redirect. I've tinkered enough that its probably worth re-posting the code.  I've edited to original question with my code so you can see what I've got.

Comment: I don't know the correct syntax but you need to do something like:

    If Request.Form("password") <> "secret" Then
        authenticationFailed = True
    Else
        needAuthentication = False
    End If